# PHP: file write permissions

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have been banging my head for quite a while now because of this...

I'm trying to install a MyBB forum on my virtual server (CentOS 7, apache http server, php 5.4.3) and I ran into troubles with file permissions. MyBB needs two files to be writable, one of them is `config.php` and the second one is `settings.php`, both of them in directory `inc`.

I set the permissions on both files to 666. I wrote a simple testing php page which mimics the way MyBB tests for the ability to write:

```
<?php
echo('config: ');
$configwritable = @fopen('forum/inc/config.php', 'w');
if ($configwritable) {
        echo('yes');
} else {
        echo('no');
}
echo('<br/>');
echo('settings: ');
$configwritable = @fopen('forum/inc/settings.php', 'w');
if ($configwritable) {
    echo('yes');
} else {
    echo('no');
}
?>
```

The page output is

```
config: no
settings: yes
```

but if I list the files, they show up like this

```
root@localhost# ls -l forum/inc/config.php forum/inc/settings.php 
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 krkavec krkavec 0  2. říj 22.49 forum/inc/config.php
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 krkavec krkavec 0  2. říj 22.51 forum/inc/settings.php
```

How is it possible? Both the files belong to the same user, to the same group, have the same size (zero), are in the same directory, have the same permissions, have almost the same modification time (differing by two minutes) and virtually everything else except their name is identical.

To make things even more weird, I tried to play around with deleting and creating the files again, watch:

1: deleting both files

```
root@localhost# rm -f forum/inc/config.php forum/inc/settings.php
```

and the page output:

```
config: no
settings: no
```

which is ok since the `inc` directory isn't supposed to be writable.

2: create `settings.php`

```
root@localhost# F=forum/inc/settings.php ; touch $F ; chown krkavec:krkavec $F ; chmod 666 $F
root@localhost# ls -l forum/inc/settings.php forum/inc/config.php
ls: cannot access forum/inc/config.php: No such file or directory
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 krkavec krkavec 0  2. říj 23.15 forum/inc/settings.php
```

and the page output:

```
config: no
settings: yes
```

which is totally ok and expected - the file is there and has writable permissions.

3: create `config.php`

```
root@localhost# F=forum/inc/config.php ; touch $F ; chown krkavec:krkavec $F ; chmod 666 $F
root@localhost# ls -l forum/inc/settings.php forum/inc/config.php
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 krkavec krkavec 0  2. říj 23.23 forum/inc/config.php
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 krkavec krkavec 0  2. říj 23.15 forum/inc/settings.php
```

and the page output:

```
config: no
settings: yes
```

BAM! I would totally expect the config to be writable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I modified the testing page according to Marc B's and drew010's suggestions

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo('config var_dump: ');
var_dump(stat('forum/inc/config.php'));
echo('<br/>config: ');
$configwritable = fopen('forum/inc/config.php', 'w');
if ($configwritable) {
    echo('yes');
} else {
    echo('no');
}
echo('<br/>');
echo('settings var_dump: ');
var_dump(stat('forum/inc/settings.php'));
echo('<br/>settings: ');
$configwritable2 = fopen('forum/inc/settings.php', 'w');
if ($configwritable2) {
    echo('yes');
} else {
    echo('no');
}
?>
```

and the page's output (with both files present) is:

```
config var_dump: array(26) { [0]=> int(64768) [1]=> int(19155212) [2]=> int(33206) [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(1000) [5]=> int(1000) [6]=> int(0) [7]=> int(0) [8]=> int(1443821772) [9]=> int(1443821772) [10]=> int(1443821772) [11]=> int(4096) [12]=> int(0) ["dev"]=> int(64768) ["ino"]=> int(19155212) ["mode"]=> int(33206) ["nlink"]=> int(1) ["uid"]=> int(1000) ["gid"]=> int(1000) ["rdev"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(0) ["atime"]=> int(1443821772) ["mtime"]=> int(1443821772) ["ctime"]=> int(1443821772) ["blksize"]=> int(4096) ["blocks"]=> int(0) } 
config: 
Warning: fopen(forum/inc/config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 8
no
settings var_dump: array(26) { [0]=> int(64768) [1]=> int(19155069) [2]=> int(33206) [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(1000) [5]=> int(1000) [6]=> int(0) [7]=> int(0) [8]=> int(1443821763) [9]=> int(1443823158) [10]=> int(1443823158) [11]=> int(4096) [12]=> int(0) ["dev"]=> int(64768) ["ino"]=> int(19155069) ["mode"]=> int(33206) ["nlink"]=> int(1) ["uid"]=> int(1000) ["gid"]=> int(1000) ["rdev"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(0) ["atime"]=> int(1443821763) ["mtime"]=> int(1443823158) ["ctime"]=> int(1443823158) ["blksize"]=> int(4096) ["blocks"]=> int(0) } 
settings: yes
```

Comment: Have you tested another variable name ? `configwritable2` for example? Additionally, omit the @-sign.

Comment: start debugging. `var_dump(stat('forum/inc/config.php'))`, and work your back up the file system chain until things start making sense.

Comment: step one: remove @ sign

Comment: Why do you bang your head? That does not help with solving a problem, you know?

Comment: @Michael removing @-sign didn't change the behaviour except there is now a warning in apache's log about not having permissions (so php really thinks it cannot open the file for writing)

Comment: Could you post the exact warning message? Have you tried if it works if you do make the inc directory writable?

Comment: What is the current test file `uid` and `gid` that includes this code snippet?

Comment: @revo the owner and group (and hence the uid and gid) of the test page file is krkavec:krkavec, i.e. the same as the config.php and settings.php

Comment: Please rename `config.php` to `config` (without extension), modify test file with new config file name, rerun test and see result. Is `config` writeable?

Comment: @revo No change: ``Warning: fopen(forum/inc/config): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 8`` (and the file is there with 666 permissions)

Comment: Are you VPS administrator? It seems some special file names are restricted from being accessed.

Comment: @revo Technically yes - I have a virtual machine which I have superuser access, but I'm just playing around with my small virual server, nothing big or even commercial. Filename seems not to be an issue - if I rename ``config.php`` to ``blahblah.php``, it still doesn't work.

Comment: So you confirm that only `settings.php` file has write permissions and not the other files with different names in the same directory?

Comment: @revo ``settings.php`` and ``config.php`` (or whatever I name it) are the only files that have write permissions for everyone: ``rw-rw-rw-``. All other files have write permissions for the owner and group only: ``rw-rw-r--``

Comment: running strace against it, on the command line should show you what's causing the permission denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some magical, unknown reason, when I renamed `settings.php` to `config.php` and then created new `settings.php` and set the rights appropriately, both files are writable.

However, I have no idea whatsoever why the file had to be renamed. The result is the same as after the step 3 described in the question except that it works.

Any suggestion why this hat to be done and the reason behind it is greatly welcome.

**EDIT**: It was caused by SELinux security context which prevented apache to write to the file. Running `chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t config.php` solved the problem.